# VBA Intenet Explorer issue with loading and achiving readystate specific webbsite

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, readystate

Dear Friends Vba Masters,
I have Issue connected with no possibility of achieved state "ready state" for my page. For others it is works for ex. google.com but I don`t know why for my page not. Strange things is that this page always load to view even in state .Visible = false , and object value od empty. I would like to create macro to login for this page and control some activities - on this page you can create some excel file to analysis. I will be very kind full. Mac.

```
Sub OpenKWM()
Dim URL As String
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("internetExplorer.application")
URL = "kwm.kromi.de"
   With IE
   .Navigate URL
  .Visible = True
  End With


 Do: Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Strange things is that this page always load to view even in state .Visible = false , and object value od empty.

If you check the [relevant doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752082(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), you will find that this is actually a reasonable result. Whether the created Internet Explorer window is visible depends on whether you have called the Navigate method or the GoSearch method. When you call these methods, the window will become visible.

**Edit**:
After testing, I found that the cause of the problem may be `Enable Protected Mode` in IE settings. You can try to disable it: `open IE` -> `Tools` -> `Internet Options` -> `security tab` -> uncheck Option `Enable Protected Mode`. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thnak You for Your answer, do You have idea for this page that i showed? It is connected with some security settings for this site?

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think your issue may be caused by this IE configuration: **Enable Protected Mode**

Comment: Thank You, that is work:) I have question about technical way, I have task to log in for this page and fill some data and generate .xls to analisys. Do you recommend "SeleniumBasis" for this task?  DO You have any expirience? [link](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases) Thank You my friend one more time for Your good :)

Comment: It looks like this solves your issue. You can mark it as an answer, which will also help other members of the community. I don't know much about the SeleniumBasic you mentioned, I'm afraid I can't give good suggestions.